# RecyclerAdapater getItemCount crashing

Tags: java, android

I have the following problem wherein my app unfortunately stops when going to the next activity. Here is the culprit :

```
   public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerHolder> {

        ArrayList<Theme> themes;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

       public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Theme> themes) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.themes = themes;
       }

        public class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            ImageView imageView;
            TextView name,price;

            public RecyclerHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.demo);
                name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
                price = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.price);
            }
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_list, viewGroup, false);
            return new RecyclerHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerHolder viewHolder, int i) {
           Log.i("log", themes.get(i).getName());
           viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(themes.get(i).getDrawableCover());
           viewHolder.name.setText(themes.get(i).getName());
           viewHolder.price.setText(themes.get(i).getPrice());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
           return themes.size();
        }
    }
```

The problem seems to lie with the `getItemCount()` method. When I try to return `themes.size()` the app crashes. When I `return 0` instead, nothing displays. What seems to be the problem here? I am new to android so please explain properly.

Comment: Please add error you are getting..and may be your themes array list is null..that may be the reason for crash.

Comment: I am not getting any error in my logcat. I've checked the the themes array list is not null as well.

Comment: If themes array list if not null and you have data in themes array list then try adding try..catch block in your onBindViewHolder method.. and cross check again..

Comment: can you try to debug and add breakpoint inside `getItemCount()` method. That way you will know for sure it's a Null pointer exception or something else.

Comment: Try to remove line of `setImageResource` on `onBindViewHolder` method, I expect resource id not valid and that is the reason of crash.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to pass `context` to the adapter as the `viewGroup` inside `onCreateViewHolder` method already has one.

Comment: Your adapter is not correct this adapter is showing error in my app also

Answer (score 3):

You would like to check if your data is `null` in `getItemCount()` method, so you would be sure that your app never crashes there:

Java:

```java
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   return themes != null ? themes.size() : 0;
}
```

Kotlin:

```kotlin
override fun getItemCount(): Int = themes?.size ?: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. This one here is the culprit `viewHolder.price.setText(themes.get(i).getPrice());` I am calling `setText()` method of a TextView and passing in an `int` value that's why it's throwing a `ResourceNotFound` exception. I have fixed it already by calling `Integer.toString()` thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you have to initialize your ArrayList.

you can initialise like this:

```
    ArrayList<Theme> themes = new ArrayList<Theme>();
```

I am not 100% sure.
but try it.